# Post form data to Rails backend from outside app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, unbounce

For marketing reasons we want to a/b test some landing pages. Fairly typical but, ideally, we'd like the page to post directly into our Rails backend (creating a new user).  We plan to host our landing pages on Unbounce (or whatever, doesn't really matter) but it's not clear how to post to (`users#create`) in Rails app from a 3rd party form without running into CSRF and other security token issues.

Perhaps there is a better (read: best practice) for how to a/b test landing pages related to a Rails application? I'm trying to minimize changes to the codebase, if possible, required to run these landing page experiments.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you're using the Rails defaults for security; you're letting the framework do good work for you! However, for what you're describing, the Rails CSRF protection defaults are going to get in the way. CSRF protection exists to protect signed-in users from having their account hijacked. Since this is your signup page, there is no signed-in user, so there's really nothing to hijack.

I recommend you do two things:

- Skip the authenticity token check *for this controller action only* (example: `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, on: :create`).
- Don't accept the signup request if there's already a signed-in user.

Comment: Also beware that if you use javascript to do your POST, cross domain protections on the browsers will kick in. If you use the standard <form POST you'll be fine.